# To Find the variance of the classifier on different datasets,How does this formula come out?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, variance, bias

To Find the variance of the classifier on different datasets, we assume sampled predictions have variance $σ^2$ and correlation $ρ$. How does this formula come out?

$$
\text{Var} (\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mh_i(x)) = \frac{1}{m}(1-p)\sigma^2 + p\sigma^2
$$

where the $h_i(x)$ is a predictors trained on dataset $i$.
 [This problem I encountered when I read the following slide](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mren/teach/csc411_19s/lec/lec04_matt.pdf)